# MongoDB. Different behavior for command line and configuration file

Tags: mongodb, command-line, configuration-files

I am testing the sharding in MongoDB

I start the configuration server first, and I use two methods to do it.

method 1/ with configuraation file (does not work)
here is my configuration file

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: "G:/data/replicas/server2/logs/server1.log"
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: "G:/data/replicas/server2/db"
  engine: wiredTiger
  journal:
      enabled: true
#security:
#  authorization: enabled
replication:
  oplogSizeMB: 128
  replSetName: rsData
#processManagement:
#   fork: true
net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
   port: 27018
```

when I run rs.initiate, I get an error.

```
> rs.initiate()
{
        "info2" : "no configuration specified. Using a default configuration for the set",
        "me" : "HORUS:27019",
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "No host described in new configuration 1 for replica set rsConfSvr maps to this node",
        "code" : 93,
        "codeName" : "InvalidReplicaSetConfig"
}
```

when I run rs.status(), after rs.initiate(), I get an error.

```
> rs.status()
{
        "info" : "run rs.initiate(...) if not yet done for the set",
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "no replset config has been received",
        "code" : 94,
        "codeName" : "NotYetInitialized"
}
```

method 2/ with command line

This works

Unless I am wrong, the command line has the same options as the config file

```
mongod --configsvr --dbpath G:/data/shards/cfgserverA/data --port 27019 --replSet rsConfigSvr --logpath "G:/data/shards/cfgserverA/logs/cfgserverA.log"
--logappend true --directoryperdb true
```

Now rs.initiate() and rs.status() work corectly.

```
 rs.initiate()
{
        "info2" : "no configuration specified. Using a default configuration for the set",
        "me" : "HORUS:27019",
        "ok" : 1
}
rsConfigSvr:OTHER>

rs.status()['configsvr']
true
```

Can someone explain? I dont understand the reason of this difference.

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**

Comment: How do I delete my question to repost it on n dba.stackexchange.com ?